# Replacement for _stdlib_getDemangledTypeName() in Swift 2.2

Tags: swift, swift2

The latest release of Swift 2.2 removes `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName()`.

What are my options to replace this?

I'm currently using in debug messages like this:

```
let debugStr = "\(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(self)) -> \(self.versionString) (\(self.versionInfo))"
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can get pretty descriptions of type names through the `String` initialiser. This should suffice as a replacement for `_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName`.

Example:

```
String(self.dynamicType)
```

Comment: Swift 3 version of this answer?  dynamicType and String() casting are now gone Could a solution be ``String(describing:type(of: self))``