# Use of unresolved identifier '_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName'

Tags: osx-elcapitan, xcode7.3, swift3

I am using [EasyTipView](http://github.com/teodorpatras/EasyTipView) library for showing the popups in iPhone application. The code was running successfully before I updated my xCode to 7.3. Now I am getting the compile time error:-

> Use of unresolved identifier '_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName'

How to resolve this issue? Is this related to any framework or what will be the updated syntax.

Comment: This may explain what's happening: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35036173/replacement-for-stdlib-getdemangledtypename-in-swift-2-2